# Mapping an IP address to local Android device (localhost)

Tags: ip-address

Is there a way to add a IP address to be a loopback to my Android device? So for example 127.0.0.1 is always the local device. I have a certain IP address that I also want to reserve just for the device just like the 127 IP and I don't want it going to the real IP. On a Windows machine I can add multiple IP addresses in the LAN adapter. Is there a way to do this in Android?

Comment: Ad-blocking apps like [Blockada](https://blokada.org) usually work this way. Unfortunately Blockada does not yet support custom black-lists, only those pre-defined lists. But in general it is technically possible even on unrooted devices using a VPN based IP/DNS-blocker app.